# How do I list configured urls in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Obviously I can do something like `cat .hg/hgrc` on *nix to see the paths I have configured, but is there a built-in Mercurial command? A Google search for "hg list configured urls" didn't seem to have any useful results, and neither does `hg help urls` (that I noticed).

Is there any command that will display the urls I have configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg paths` is what you are looking for. `hg help paths` will give you more information.

Comment: I *swear* I tried that... But looking back through my bash history apparently I just did `urls` >.< Doh!

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is indeed `hg paths` as [smooth reggae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881190/smooth-reggae) wrote, but so you know, there's also the [`showconfig` command](http://selenic.com/hg/help/showconfig), which will show you any section(s) of the combined config files.

There's not much point in using `hg showconfig paths`, which is longer to type, but it's useful for quickly checking the value of other configuration settings.